# SQL select counts on 1 value

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+------------+--------+--------------+
|   Id    |    Name    | Status | Content_type |
+---------+------------+--------+--------------+
| 2960671 | PostJob    | Error  | general_url  |
| 2960670 | auto_index | Done   | general_url  |
| 2960669 | auto_index | Done   | document     |
| 2960668 | auto_index | Error  | document     |
| 2960667 | auto_index | Error  | document     |
+---------+------------+--------+--------------+
```

And I want to count how many of each type that has 'Error' as status, so in the result it would be `1x general_url` and `2x document`

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Content_type) from Indexing where Status = 'Error';
```

But I could not figure out how to get the content_type out of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this

```
select Content_type, 
       count(Status) 
from Indexing 
where Status='Error' 
group by Content_type;
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY should do the job:

```
SELECT Content_type, COUNT(Id) from Indexing where Status = 'Error' GROUP BY Content_type;
```

**Explanation:**

`COUNT (x)` counts the number of rows in the *group*, `COUNT (*)` would do the same.

`COUNT (DISTINCT x)` counts the number of distinct values in the *group*.

Without a `GROUP BY` clause the *group* is the whole set of records, so in your example you would have seen a single value (2) as your result; i.e. there are 2 distinct Content_types in the set.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9f6c/5)

**Schema**

```
create table test
(id varchar2(10),
name varchar2(30),
status varchar2(20),
content_type varchar2(30)
);

 insert into test values('2960671','PostJob','Error','general_url');
 insert into test values('2960670','auto_index','Done','general_url');
 insert into test values('2960669','auto_index','Done','document');
 insert into test values('2960668','auto_index','Error','document');
 insert into test values('2960667','auto_index','Error','document');
```

**Select Query**

```
SELECT  LISTAGG(content_type, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rownum) AS content_type,
count(content_type) as content_type_count
from
(
select distinct(content_type) content_type
FROM   test
where status='Error'
);
```

**Output**

```
|         CONTENT_TYPE | CONTENT_TYPE_COUNT |
|----------------------|--------------------|
| document,general_url |                  2 |
```

The idea here is to print comma separated content_type values so that you can know the count of content_type along with actual values

Comment: wow, this looks nice, but it doesn't sohw that only 1 general_url failed :)

Comment: Seems i did not understand the question well. I suppose you got your answer though

Answer (score 0):

Try this One

```
SELECT count(`content_type`) as 'count', content_type as 'x content type' FROM `tablename` where status= 'Error' group by(`content_type`)
```